# A really robust way to escape URL in Java?

Tags: java, url

I'm running a tiny web crawler so I really need a way to manage all discovered URLs in a unified manner. So, I've decided the standard to be a percent-encoded URL with a punycode hostname. How do I convert whatever piece of garbage parser finds into a properly escaped URL? So far I came up with the following code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.IDN;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class URLEscaper {

 public static String toURI(String url) throws Exception {

    if (url == null) return null;

    // The input string might already be an escaped url, so decode
    // it first, which is an idempotent operation:
    URL u = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8"));

    String scheme = u.getProtocol();
    String usercreds = u.getUserInfo();
    String host = IDN.toASCII(u.getHost());
    int port = u.getPort();
    String path = u.getPath();
    String query = u.getQuery();
    String fragment = u.getRef();
    URI result = new URI(scheme, usercreds, host, port, path, query, fragment);

    return result.toASCIIString();

 }
}
```

The problem with this function is java.net.URI strict following RFC, which states that a hostname cannot contain any symbols besides `[a-z0-9-]`. So if a hostname contains, say underscore '_' then URI constructor will throw URISyntaxException. And there is a whole lot of perfectly accessible websites on the Internet, that contain an underscore in the hostname. And I wouldn't like to lose those. What can I use instead of java.net.URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it works with Apache's commons-httpclient version of URI implementation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Simple test

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI uri = new URI("http://a_domain_with_underscores.com:8080/demo/index.hp?query=param", true);
System.out.println(uri.getHost());
```

And you get the domain printed in the console

```
a_domain_with_underscores.com
```

It doesn't work for apache commons 4, different maven groupId/artifact because apache has dropped the in-house implementation of URI and stuck to `java.net.URI` instead; the nice thing about it is that Apache provides a nice `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` instead of those ugly `java.net.URI` constructors :)

This is the latest version of Apache's http client artifact...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So the code would look like this instead

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
uriBuilder.setScheme("http").setHost("a_domain_with_underscores.com").setPort(8080);
java.net.URI builtURI = uriBuilder.build();
System.out.println(builtURI.getHost());
```

And you'd end up with a nasty `null` in the console for this